# Plot and save multiple figures

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that have 300 columns
I want to make multiple plot saved in 1 file that show the relation between variable in column 200 and all the other columns of my data frame, so column 1 to 199 and 201 to 300.
If possible also to have a script that do the same thing but saving each graph in a specific file.

Example

```
qplot(data$column200,data$column1, geom=c("violin", "boxplot" ), main="Female")
qplot(data$column200,data$column2, geom=c("violin", "boxplot" ), main="Female")
qplot(data$column200,data$column3, geom=c("violin", "boxplot" ), main="Female")
qplot(data$column200,data$column300, geom=c("violin", "boxplot" ), main="Female")
```

and finally save all those graphs.

Thanks

Comment: [This link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/) looks like it could do this automatically, but if you wanted to have more control, then I'd use `jpeg()` command. [Details available here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html)

Comment: my advice: reshape the data to long format with `reshape2::melt`. Everything is easier from there on.

Comment: Do you have any script ready to use to do this?